# Create a histogram for 'transactionAmount' for processed transactions, i.e; for same account number if PURCHASE should not be followed by a REVERSAL

Tags: python, loops

So, below I should get the histogram for 9000,8000,7000 transaction amount. I tried the below code but unable to print histogram.

```
 df = pd.DataFrame({'accnumber': [123, 123, 456, 456,789],
               'transType': ['PURCHASE', 'REVERSAL', 'PURCHASE', 'PURCHASE', 'PURCHASE'],
               'transAmount': [100, 100, 9000, 8000, 7000]})
row_iterator = df.iterrows()
_, previous = next(row_iterator)
for i, next_row in row_iterator:
 if previous['accnumber'] == next_row['accnumber'] and previous['transType'] == 'PURCHASE' and next_row['transType'] == 'PURCHASE':
        df.transAmount.plot(kind="hist",bins=10,linewidth=200,figsize=(9,10))
        plt.title('Histogram of the processed amounts of each transaction')
```

Comment: _but unable to print histogram._ What happens?

Comment: Code is not returning anything, Execute the above code!!

Comment: The imports are missing. Is that the only thing?

Comment: In order to run the code we need to import the correct modules, right?

Comment: No, the issue is not with the imports, I checked. If I change next_row['transType'] == 'REVERSAL', I'm getting the histogram, but that is not correct.!!